# How can I make bash use color coded output by default?

Tags: colors, bashrc, terminal-emulator

I was recently trying to get `node.js` up and running. One of the steps required that I add an export line to my `.bashrc` file. Upon doing so, and rebooting the machine, the output of the bash terminal is no longer color-coded.

I have tried copying the default with `cp /etc/skel/.bashrc ~/.bashrc` and then un-commenting the line `force_color_prompt=yes`. But when I reboot the machine, the output is still black and white.

If I run `source .bashrc` or `. .bashrc` the output works as expected (it's color coded). But this is not the default behavior on login.

How can I set bash to use the color-coded output by default upon login?

Comment: What is your `PS1`?

Comment: You can define color prompt in `PS1`environment. If you haven't set any color, there will be no colors.

Comment: I haven't messed with PS1 at all. Only with the .bashrc files. SO I don't think that this is the root of the issue.

Comment: just pointing out, that `source .bashrc` or `. .bashrc` are the same things

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be possible that your `.profile` does not load the `.bashrc` file.

```
cat ~/.profile
```

Should look somewhat similar to:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

But there are many other places to check:

Are you really running `bash`:

```
ls -l $SHELL
```

If so, be sure to look into all of these, (if they exist):

1. `/etc/profile`
2. `~/.bash_profile`
3. `~/.bash_login`
4. `~/.profile`

If the output of `ls -l ~/.bashrc` contains `root` as owner/group:

```
sudo chown $USER:$USER ~/.bashrc
```

Also, the intended user rights are `644` meaning:

```
ls -l ~/.bashrc
```

gives output of:

```
-rw-r--r--
```

If not, change it as follows:

```
chmod 644 ~/.bashrc
```